# Smooth update top subview while dragging one of the bottom subviews (iOS)

Tags: ios, ipad

I have a lot of small draggable subviews in my iPad app. I have also a top non-opaque subview with clear color background. It has screen size. User interaction is disabled for it. I need to redraw that top subview while I am dragging one of the bottom subviews. I draw some lines on that top subview. They have to be redrawed according with current bottom subview position.  I want achieve smooth dragging but currently I can't. Currently I send a lot of setNeedsDisplayInRect to top view in panMoved of my bottom subview.
How to do that better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to use CALayer of the top subview for drawing. It's much more effective.